# Insert complete repeated row under condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically, I'm trying to consider the third column (df1[3]) if the value is higher or equal to 2 I want to repeat i.e insert the whole row to a new row, not to replace.

Here is the dataframe:

```
    1           2       3    
   
0   5614    banana      1   
1   4564    kiwi        1   
2   3314    salsa       2   
3   3144    avocado     1   
4   1214    mix         3   
5   4314    juice       1
```

desired output:

```
    1           2       3       
1   5614    banana      1   
2   4564    kiwi        1   
3   3314    salsa       2   
4   3314    salsa       2  
5   3144    avocado     1   
6   1214    mix         3   
7   1214    mix         3 
8   1214    mix         3 
7   4314    juice       1
```

code for the DataFrame and attempt to solve it:

```
l = [5614,4564,3314,3144,1214,4314]
i = ['banana','kiwi' ,'salsa','avocado','mix','juice']
n = [1,1,2,1,3,1]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = (1,2,3))
df1[1] = l
df1[2] = i
df1[3] = n

    for indx,row in df.iterrows():
        if row[3].isdigit() == True and int(row[3]) >= 2:
            df1.loc[indx] = [row * int(row[3])]
```

Obviously, the above-stated approach doesn't create a new row with the same values from each column but replaces it.

Append() wouldn't solve it either because I do have to preserve the exact same order of the data frame.

Is there anything similar to insert/extend/add or slicing approach in list when it comes to pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `repeat`:

```
count = pd.to_numeric(df['3'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)

# replace '3' with actual column name
df.loc[df.index.repeat(count)]
```

Output:

```
      1        2  3
0  5614   banana  1
1  4564     kiwi  1
2  3314    salsa  2
2  3314    salsa  2
3  3144  avocado  1
4  1214      mix  3
4  1214      mix  3
4  1214      mix  3
5  4314    juice  1
```

Comment: Can you explain how would I control the condition such as; int(df1[3])  >= 2 ? since they are all strings in my case

Comment: @Ecko replace `fillna(0)` with `fillna(1)` if you want to keep the rows that `df[3]` is not numerical.